# formgroupname have same index in ngfor

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I have created a formarray that allows me to add several fields with the same name but different values but the problem is that when I fill a field the others with the same name are filled automatically . it like is always in the index 0 and don"t loop with `*ngfor`.

```js
   actions: FormGroup;
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
      this.actions = this.formBuilder.group({
        acts: this.formBuilder.array([]) ,
      });
    }
acts() : FormArray {
  return this.actions.get("acts") as FormArray
}
newActs(): FormGroup {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    n_action: new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
    action_libel:new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
    
  })
}
addaction() {
  this.acts().push(this.newActs());
}
removeAct(i:number) {
  this.acts().removeAt(i);
  console.log("this is ",i)
}
```

```html
<button type="button" (click)="addaction()" class="btn btn-primary">
    <mat-icon>add_circle_outline</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <div class=" form-group" formArrayName="acts">
   
<div [formGroupName]="i" *ngFor="let action of acts().controls; let i=index">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Action N°:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="n_action" id="n_action"  required [(ngModel)]="analysefnc.n_action" name="n_action">
      <span *ngIf="action.controls.n_action.errors?.required">required</span>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Action:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="action_libel" id="action_libel"  required [(ngModel)]="analysefnc.action_libel" name="action_libel">
      <span *ngIf="action.controls.action_libel.errors?.required">required</span>

    </div>
   
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding to `[formGroupName]='i'` before you declare `i`

Change your HTML to

```html
<div *ngFor="let action of acts().controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">

    <!-- Other code here -->
   
  </div>
```

**Edit**

For the new error you may need to change `acts()` to a getter e.g

```typescript
   actions: FormGroup;
   constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
      this.actions = this.formBuilder.group({
        acts: this.formBuilder.array([]) ,
      });
    }
   get acts() : FormArray {
     return this.actions.get("acts") as FormArray
   }
   newActs(): FormGroup {
     return this.formBuilder.group({
        n_action: new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
        action_libel:new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
    
    })
}
addaction() {
  this.acts.push(this.newActs());
}
removeAct(i:number) {
  this.acts.removeAt(i);
  console.log("this is ",i)
}
```

and in the HTML

```html
  <button type="button" (click)="addaction()" class="btn btn-primary">
    <mat-icon>add_circle_outline</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <div class=" form-group" formArrayName="acts">
    <div *ngFor="let action of acts.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Action N°:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            formControlName="n_action"
            id="n_action"
            required
            name="n_action"
          />
          <span *ngIf="action.get('n_action').errors?.required">required</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Action:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            formControlName="action_libel"
            id="action_libel"
            required
            name="action_libel"
          />
          <span *ngIf="action.get('action_libel').errors?.required"
            >required</span
          >
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[See this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nasjce?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: the index has changed but the field  still have  fixed value

Comment: when I add two or 3 actions , and set N°action field to value "1" all others field N°action take value "1" and even if I change the second to  value "2 " all others fields take same value

Comment: I get this error on console when I click on button  add actionExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked

Comment: No , I m still trying to find a solution

Comment: I edited as you said but I still have the same error ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value:

Comment: I have the same value in all fields who have same name

Comment: Check now, I have included a demo for reference

Comment: okay so you removed ngmodel , this worked for me but how I can insert this data now when I removed ngmodel ?

Comment: It is wrong to use ngModel with formControlName in the same control. If you need the value you can simply access it by `acts.controls[i].value`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227272/discussion-between-hamza-nouri-and-owen-kelvin).